# Component 'Y' must be declared(update another table with one component)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Got a problem "Component 'Y' must be declared" while it is declared. How the code should be fixed?

AB table has PN variable the same that PARTS has.
OR maybe is there another way to update table with other table info when pn matches?

```html
DECLARE
   CURSOR C1 IS
  SELECT  *  FROM AB LEFT JOIN PARTS ON AB.PN=PARTS.PN where AB.FH_FC_WOF = 'FH' AND AB.OPERATION = 'OH' AND ab.pn=parts.pn ;
BEGIN
 FOR i in C1
 LOOP
   UPDATE PARTS
   SET PARTS.OH_HOURS = i.FLIGHT_DURATION
   WHERE  PARTS.PN=i.PN;  
 END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Comment:"WHERE ... AND ab.pn=parts.pn" makes the LEFT JOIN behave like a regular innner join. If you really want an outer join, move that condition to the ON clause!

Comment: Thank you, i need to use cursor. Already solved a problem which was in join operation, i could not select * as then it has two columns with same data

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a cursor? Can't you just do an UPDATE:

```
update parts p1 set p1.OH_HOURS = (select FLIGHT_DURATION
                                   from FROM AB LEFT JOIN PARTS ON AB.PN = PARTS.PN
                                   where AB.FH_FC_WOF = 'FH' AND AB.OPERATION = 'OH'
                                     AND ab.pn = p1.pn)
```

Is it possible that the sub-select may return more than 1 row? If that's the case you might change to  `= (select MAX(FLIGHT_DURATION)`, or restrict the result to 1 row in some other way (FETCH FIRST etc.)

Comment: Thank you, i need to use cursor. Already solved a problem which was in join operation, i could not select * as then it has two columns with same data